# TCP request handling efficiency

Tags: vb.net, tcp, request

I'm building a TCP server app and had a question regarding the efficiency of my request handlig code. I now simply use cases to determine what kind of request it is, through its request code(for instance 301 means a login). But I wanted to know if this is the best and most efficient way to handle the requests. Any and all suggestions are welcome.

This Sample shows in simple how I handle the requests:

```
Select Case Code
 Case 301
  'Handling code goes here
 Case Else
  'Handling code goes here
End Select
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance wise you're going to see very little overhead using Select Case.  Personally though I'd use an Enum rather than just having hard coded intergers ie:

```
   Private Enum TCPRequest
        login = 301
        LogOut = 302
    End Enum

        Dim Request As TCP Request = 301

        Select Case Request
            Case TCPRequest.login
                '   Login Code  
            Case TCPRequest.LogOut
                '   Logout Code
        End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using WCF instead of implementing your own server?

Comment: I indeed did and I'm migrating my server to WCF right now. But it'll take a while before that is done and I thought maybe there is a way to  make it all a bit more efficient.